Pyspark | how to convert a column value from String to new dataframe?
The existing dataframe is



header
body




xxx
'{"name":"john","age":20,"emails":["xxx1@gmail.com","xxx2@yahoo.com"]}'


xxx
'{"name":"jerry","age":30,"emails":["xxx1@gmail.com","xxx2@yahoo.com"]}'



its schema:
root
 --body: string(nullable = true)
 --header: string(nullable = true)

I want to extract column 'body' and convert it from string to a new dataframe as below:



name
age
emails




john
20
["xxx1@gmail.com","xxx2@yahoo.com"]


jerry
30
["xxx1@gmail.com","xxx2@yahoo.com"]



I tried
df1 = df.withColumn('body', sf.to__json(sf.col('body', ArrayType(StringType)))
but got 'elementType <class 'pyspark.sql.types.StringType'> should be an instance of <class 'pyspark.sql.types.DataType'> '
Also tried df1 = df.select("body.*")
got error 'can only star expand struct data type, attribute arraybuffer(body)'
how to convert the column'body' from String to new dataframe in a effective way?

I am voting to close the question because it's been answered already; df.select(F.json_tuple(F.col('body'),"name","age","emails")).toDF('name','age','emails') would be the way to go I think

@DerekO I followed the answer you shared, got error "all arguments must be strings. Project [json_tuple(name, age, emails)...."

@DerekO oh I got it, now it works. Thank you!
